# Can't pass the segment parameter for a profile Google analytics's API V3, get 400 invalid value

Tags: php, analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using PHP client library with the Google Anaytlics API v3. So far I have drilled all the way to fetching the data from the profiles. I can fetch all visits from a profile, but when I decide to use segments to find out how many referral visits or paid search visits there are, the whole code breaks with the following error.

Uncaught exception 'apiServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%XXX&start-date=2012-02-01&end-date=2012-02-29&metrics=ga%3Avisits&segment=gaid%3A%3A10&key=XXXX: (400) Invalid Value'

This is the code that's causing the problems. I pass in the optional segments parameter correctly using the key and string value but it still comes up with the error

```
<?php
$data = $service -> data_ga -> get("ga:".$profile -> getId(), "2012-02-01", "2012-02-29", 'ga:visits', array("segment" => "gaid::10"));

?>
```

I have crossed out parts of the request as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, in order to pass the segment in and avoid a 400 error.

Instead of this

```
 <?php
    $data = $service -> data_ga -> get("ga:".$profile -> getId(), "2012-02-01", "2012-02-29",      'ga:visits', array("segment" => "gaid::7"));

?>
```

Use the symbol - before the segment id number like this

```
<?php
$data = $service -> data_ga -> get("ga:".$profile -> getId(), "2012-02-01", "2012-02-29", 'ga:visits', array("segment" => "gaid::-7"));

?>
```

I have no idea why this works, I found the solution on another forum post here

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-analytics-data-export-api/segment$20v3/google-analytics-data-export-api/hfnaZSdR2FY/IKBUJdkFdUYJ

Comment: +1; what helped me is pointing out that, unlike all the other fields, segment uses a double colon in its prefix.